# I got an error when I try to getSelectedValue() from a JList to another JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying as it says the title, to get the selected item on a `JList` and add it to the second `JList` when I press a Button:

```
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


 list_1.addElement(list.getSelectedValue());

}});
```

So, when I write that, in `AddElement` it asks me to cast `list_1` to an `Object`, looking like this, becasue of this error:
[image]

Then after adding the Cast as it asks me to, I got the same error like if I didn't added anything.

So my question is, how do I add something from one `JList` to another `JList` when pressing a button? And if I will have the same problems for removing the last item added, or the selectedItem, please let me know how to prevent it.

The full code:

```
JList list = new JList();
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
list.setModel(new AbstractListModel(){
    String[] values = new String[] {"Aceite de oliva", "Aceitunas negras", "Aceitunas verdes", "Albahaca", "Alcachofa", "Anchoas", "Berenjena", "Cebolla", "Cereza", "Champiniones", "Durazno", "Harina de garbanzo", "Huevo", "Jam\u00F3n", "Jam\u00F3n serrano", "Ma\u00EDz", "Morr\u00F3n rojo", "Morr\u00F3n verde", "Or\u00E9gano", "Palmitos", "Pi\u00F1a", "Queso cheddar", "Queso crema", "Queso gorgonzola ", "Queso muzzarella", "Queso parmesano", "Salame", "Tomates", "Tomillo"};

    public int getSize() {
        return values.length;
    }

    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return values[index];
    }
});

list.setToolTipText("");
list.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane_1.setBounds(373, 28, 184, 257);
contentPane.add(scrollPane_1);

JList list_1 = new JList();
list_1.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
    String[] values2 = new String[] {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
    public int getSize() {
        return values2.length;
    }
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return values2[index];
    }
 });

 list_1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
 scrollPane_1.setViewportView(list_1);
```

[image]

I have visited a lot of websites with different kind of Lists / Models, and as I really don't get how to use `JList`s I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `Object` to the `DefaultListModel` of the `JList`.

You can use the `addElement(...)` method of the `DefaultListModel`.

> i really don't get how to use JLists

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for JList basics. The `"Hire"` button from the `ListDemo` example will show you how to do this. It uses the `insertElementAt(...)` method but the concept is the same.

Comment: yes, but the problem i have when visiting other websites is that they have a name to call the model, i don't, as by default clicked the Jlist and moved it to the right place, eclipse writed to me some kind of Method of AbstractListModel, but i don't know how to call it.

BTW: I quote what the website you gave me says: listModel.insertElementAt(employeeName.getText(), index);

Well imagining i can do that part, don't i have to change anything, exactly as it is (except adding the object to the defaultListModel) ?

Comment: I suggested you use the `addElement()` method. It just adds the object to the end of the model. The `insertElementAt(...)` is only if you want to add the object to a specific postion. I don't care about other websites. The tutotorial link has a complete working example. So structure your code like the example and you won't have a problem.

Comment: Ok, i did this:  list_1.addElement() = list.getSelectedValue();

But now i get a new error: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"
I mean, i believe list_1 it's a variable, so i don't get the problem again

Comment: Read the tutorial. Download the example code and play with the working example to understand how it works!!! Your code will be slightly different. Instead of getting the Object from a JTextField you get the object form the JList. Then you add the Object to the DefaultListModel of the second JList. You don't add the Object to the JList directly!!! You don't learn if you don't read the tutorial. Don't just keep asking a question when you get a compile error. You need to understand WHY you are writing the code.

Comment: i am reading and studying it since yesterday, so i have a question: Why can't i call 'index' ? It asks me to create the local variable, but it's created in the method getElementAt(int index)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking. Using methods and variables is basic java. If you have a problem understand a Java concept then you need to create a simple program that demonstrates what you are trying to do. This is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). So in this case you might create a JFrame with a JList and a JButton. When you click on a button you get the selected item. The whole class should be about 20-30 lines of code. If you still have a problem then ask a new question and post your SSCCE.